# Dask client upload_file from S3 using python shell AWS glue

Tags: aws-glue, dask-distributed

I am trying to execute python shell job in Glue using Dask client. Since i have helper .py files, that is required to carry out the job, I tried to execute :

**client.upload_file('.py path in s3')**

I get error: directory not found.
Can you please help how to upload_file s3 py files?

Note: My workers are running and i have added my py,whl files in glue python library path and referenced files path.